# Apply helper to all collections mongodb/meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

[There is a library that allows you to attach helpers to collections](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers) like so:

```
Meteor.users.helpers({
  profile: function() {
    return Profiles.findOne(this.profileId);
  }
});
```

This works great for established collections, but I want to make "general" helpers that apply to ever single collection in my database by default.

```
EveryCollection.helpers({
  fullName: function() {
    var schema = this.simpleSchema()._schema;
    if(hasKey(schema, 'firstName') && hasKey(schema, 'lastName')) {
      return getKey(this, 'firstName') + " " + getKey(this, 'lastName');
    }
  }
});
```

That way, I could do this:

```
> Admins.findOne().fullName();
"Cat Woman"
> Meteor.users.findOne().fullName();
"Bat Man"
```

This would be, by default, added to every collection as a helper. Is this possible? I imagine it requires adding something to the `prototype`, but can't find the proper item to add it to.

EDIT: poor example, wanted something that worked on an instance variable

Answer (score 0):

```
Mongo.Collection.prototype.idMap = function () {
  return this.find().map(function (doc) {
    return doc._id;
  });
};
Meteor.users.idMap();
```

PS, there's nothing too magical about the collections helper package, and if you check out line #1 of the code, you'll see your answer ;)

https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers/blob/master/collection-helpers.js